# How to hide an the HTML element if a JSON key doesn't exist in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, show-hide

I'm trying to hide or show an HTML element based on the existence of a JSON key in the data I'm bringing in. If the key exists, I'd like to show the element ID I'm putting that object in. If the key doesn't exist, I'd like to hide the same element ID. I'm using React and not sure if this belongs in the componentDidMount or a regular function. I'm a newbie, so my apologies if I accidentally leave out important code or am writing crappy stuff.

My `componentDidMount` code:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  // Need to hide an the HTML element if the json key doesn't exist in the object
  //check the JSON object for the key "workExamples"
  if (typeof props.workItemData.workExamples === "undefined") {
    console.log("it did not find the json key");
    // Change element styling to hidden
    document.getElementById("work-examples").style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else {
    return;
  }
};
```

My HTML:

```
<span id="work-examples" className="work-examples">
  <a href={props.workItemData.workExamples}>Work Examples</a>
</span>
```

I'm assuming I don't need to post my JSON objects. I have several; only one has the `workExamples` key. I'm using `.map()` to list the objects.

With the above code, it's not hiding the elements in the list for the JSON objects that don't have the key. Hopefully this all makes sense. Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Luke notes in the comments,

> the logic for whether or not to render should live in `render`

Mechanics of this have since been covered by other answers here, so I won't go through it all.

A few other points:

You're trying to use an arrow function to define the standard React function `componentDidMount`, and based on a quick local test, I don't think React can understand that. It doesn't look like you're getting any particular benefit from it over the traditional `componentDidMount() { /* do stuff here */ }` syntax, so I'd switch to the latter.

You're trying to check on whether your JSON contains the key with

```
typeof props.workItemData.workExamples === "undefined"
```

but I don't see a need for the `typeof`; you can just check for the presence of the key directly:

```
if(props.workItemData.workExamples) { /* do stuff */ }
```

Finally, in your HTML, the line

```
<a href={props.workItemData.workExamples}>Work Examples</a>
```

is attempting to set the value of `href` with a value from JavaScript (the stuff in the curly braces). That's valid for [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html), which makes sense since you're using React, but not in pure HTML. But since the page is loading and just not handling a certain part of the logic correctly, I'm assuming you just meant the HTML-like stuff inside your JSX (a `something.js` file) and not literally an HTML file.

Comment: Good callouts, but the important thing here is that the logic for whether or not to render should live in `render`.

Comment: Ah, missed the forest for the trees on this one. Thanks for the tip (I'm new to React too).

Comment: `if(props.workItemData.workExamples) { /* do stuff */ }` ended up being what I needed. I put that in a `componentDidMount` and if it found that JSON key it changed an element ID from hidden to visible. I think I understand everyone's comments saying that I may not need an entire `componentDidMount` and could just drop the logic inside the `render`? I know I'm not versed enough in all this to quickly and efficiently describe things - my apologies. I'm learning.... but I do thank you all.

Comment: I don't think people are saying you don't need `componentDidMount` in general, it depends what else you're doing in there. Official docs link: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount As I understood it, the message was that using `render` is the "React way" of doing things (and it _is_ a fundamental part of React). Even if there are no weird interactions with other code, you get a maintainability benefit, since other devs or even future-you will probably look for rendering stuff to be there and not expect it elsewhere. You know, separation of concerns, cohesion, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
render(){
   return props.workItemData.workExamples && (
      <span id="work-examples" className="work-examples"> 
        <a href={props.workItemData.workExamples}>Work Examples</a>
      </span>)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted doesn't really make any sense. You should read up on React and how it works. You wouldn't ever need to DOM-select-by-ID an HTML element being rendered by a React component from within that React component. Instead, you simply have the React component's render function check your conditional and then render the HTML accordingly.

Except that actually here, you don't even to do that, because if you're using map the way that I think you are (you didn't post your data so it's hard to tell), then you can just generate an HTML element for each item in the array. So if it's not in the array, it won't map().

```
render() {
    let workItems = this.props.workItemData ? this.props.workItemData.map((item) =>
        <span id={Object.keys(item)[0]} className={Object.keys(item)[0]}>
            <a href={item[Object.keys(item)[0]]}>{Object.keys(item)[0]}</a>
        </span>
    ) : '';

    return (
        <div>
         {workItems}
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Upvoting this. The other proposed solutions work just fine but you actually provide a reason why the OP's method doesn't make any sense when using React.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just taking the prop and potentially outputting it, you could keep it simple and just name what you need in a variable.

```
render() {
  let conditionalElement = null;
  if(props.workItemData.workExamples) {
    conditionalElement = (
      <span id="work-examples" className="work-examples">
        <a href={props.workItemData.workExamples}>Work Examples</a>
      </span>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {conditionalElement}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This will allow you to have a null value which can be injected into JSX if need be (won't produce anything), then check if the prop is there, and then replace the null value with your JSX.

Also, yes, go with the standard componentDidMount() {} function syntax and typeof would have been unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove objects without the key before any of their corresponding components have been created. Something like:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        Object.keys(workItems)
        .filter(item => item.workExamples)
        .map(item => <YourComponent {...item} />)
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In React I wanted to display only existing elements after mapping, so in the list element I added CSS logic:

```
 render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        data.map ((item) => {
        return (<div>

    <li>{item.answer1}</li>
    <li>{item.answer2}</li>
    <li>{item.answer3}</li>
    <li style = {{display: item.answer4 ? 'block' : 'none'}}> 
     {item.answer4}</li>
    <li style = {{display: item.answer5 ? 'block' : 'none'}}> 
     {item.answer5}</li>
    <li style = {{display: item.answer6 ? 'block' : 'none'}}> 
      {item.answer6}</li>
```

)
         )
          }
        
      )
    }